# Ruby active record inserting datetime instead of time in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

Rails Active Record save uses `datetime` in insert query although the datatype is `time` in mysql and time is set in model before saving

mysql schema:

```
rtime time DEFAULT NULL
```

ActiveRecord model: Abc

```
abc = Abc.new {'rtime'=> '18:23 PM'}
abc.save!
```

corresponding mysql query generated by active record:

```
insert into abces (rtime) values('2000-01-01 18:23:00');
```

Later in mysql only the time is stored and date is sliced off, and a warning is also generated.

```
+-----------------------+
| rtime                 |
+-----------------------+
| 18:23:00              |
+-----------------------+`
```

Why is the date appended with time while mysql insertion?
Rails version: 3.2.16

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ActiveRecord often falls back to a DateTime object when assigning a Time in Rails 3+: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L130

There's some documentation on the conversion method here: http://apidock.com/rails/Time/time_with_datetime_fallback/class. Also, there's a comment that hints at this on line 180 of the same file: `# we instantiate Time object and convert it back to a date thus using Time's logic in handling invalid dates`

Thus it seems Rails 3 often treats `Time` objects as though they were `DateTime`s, which explains the odd insert query you're seeing. The behavior seems to be changed in Rails 4 so upgrading may resolve the issue.

In any case the date values seem to simply get truncated by MySQL hence the warning, but the stored time seems correct to me.

Finally, do you need a timezone for this time?

Comment: I don't need a timezone for the time. And yes I understand rails is doing it. It does it in select queries as well. Just wondering if there is a way to switch it off somehow. Upgrading rails would a risky thing, so I would probably just make a native mysql query and run that directly.